# Why is a "local observable" given by $\exp\left(-i\sum_j a_j \hat{P}_j + b_j \hat{Q}_j\right)$ and not just $\sum_j a_j \hat{P}_j + b_j \hat{Q}_j$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space

I've been trying to understand this long-standing paper:

https://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0607044

regarding the claimed impossibility of defining a sense in which one can say that *relativistic* quantum particles, i.e. in the sense of Relativistic Quantum Field Theory (RQFT), have a localized position and which then is likewise often used to suggest that thus "particles" don't really exist in the theory - a question I've also puzzled over for some time. Namely, the author, much as I would have thought, works through the problem using phonons in a crystal lattice as the example, but he then gives this definition of a "localized observable" on page 6 that I don't get because it has an exponential function around it: he calls

$$\exp\left(-i \sum_{j \in B} \left[a_j \hat{P}_j + b_j \hat{Q}_j\right]\right)$$

a "localized observable" and notes these form an algebra.

Now I believe the variables above are that the one-dimensional oscillator chain or lattice is to hold $N$ "atoms", $j$ is an index over the atoms drawn from a subset $B$ of the total indices (from $0$ to $N-1$), so the idea is this represents an observable localized to only those atoms in $B$, with the text that such an operator as above should be thought of as one that depends solely on the lattice-point operators $\hat{P}_j$ and $\hat{Q}_j$ (which presumably are just the atomic displacement momentum $\hat{p}_j$ and position $\hat{x}_j$). Now that text makes good sense - if it depends only on those lattice points then it is localized to them. But here's the thing: why the exponential? To me, I'd have thought to define such an operator as just any (Hermitian) element of the algebra generated by the generator set $\{ \hat{x}_j, \hat{p}_j : j \in B \}$ *directly*, e.g. $\frac{1}{2}\hat{x}_0 - \hat{x}_1 \hat{p}_1 + \hat{p}_1 \hat{x}_1$ is strictly localized to $B = \{ 0, 1 \}$. Is this inequivalent in an important way?

Comment: can you clarify if there is one or two sums and if the “i” multiplies the entire expression on the right or just the sum over $P_j$’s?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero: My assumption is since the index variable $j$ appears in both, both should go inside the sum, but I added brackets to make that clearer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a technicality: Since the "raw" momentum and position operators are unbounded with continuous spectrum, they are mathematically not very "well-behaved". For instance, while the [Stone-von Neumann theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93von_Neumann_theorem) guarantees the uniqueness of the representation of the exponentiated form of the CCR ("Weyl relations")
$$ \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}tx}\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}sp} = \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}st}\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}sp}\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}tx}$$
this does not hold if we merely have the raw CCR
$$ [x,p] = \mathrm{i}.$$
Therefore, texts focused on mathematical rigor will often prefer to talk in terms of the exponentiated algebra as the "algebra of observables" because it has nicer properties. Note that demanding a proper representation of the exponentiated algebra is a strictly stronger requirement, since you get back the non-exponentiated operators by $(\partial_t \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}tx})\rvert_{t= 0}$.